# Azure Automation Index Maintenance Failure

Tags: azure, indexing, automation

I am using Azure Automation for index maintenance. Azure Automation fails with this error:

"A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded."

It fails on Re-Organizing an index. 
Does anybody know how I can fix this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue by adding re-run logic around the step that was failing; I highly recommend adding re-run logic anywhere that you think it might timeout and write your code such a way that it is re-runnable.